# adding UIGestureRecognizer setter method not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What i need to do is to add a View and then have a single Tap Recognizer where when the user taps on the screen, then a NSLog will be displayed;

This is what i did;

I added the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to my `.h` file. and in the `.m` i wrote the following code

```
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                            [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
UIGestureRecognizer *one= [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onetapmethod:)];   
[one setDelegate:self];
[one setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
[view addGestureRecognizer:one];
```

I am doing this according to a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVAyOO1D6S0&feature=related), and according to the tutorial i will have to add `setNumberOfTaps:1` but when it says that the setter method is not found.

Why is this ?

and how can i edit my code for this to work ?

Is my code correct ? (adding the gestureRecogniser to view `[view addGestureRecognizer:one];`) ?

Comment: Which method is not found? Can you give the line of code that is actually giving the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use UITapGestureRecognizer instead of UIGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using UITapGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

`setNumberOfTaps` is not a valid UIGestureRecognizer method. You may mean `setNumberOfTapsRequired:` but this is a method of UITapGestureRecognizer, which is a subclass of UIGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have answered, you should use a UITapGestureRecognizer.  Only, I'll provide you with some information:

See [UITapGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [various examples](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html) using different gesture recognizers.

Comment: I went through the code, i saw this line which adds it to the view [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps]; . Is there away to remove the gestureRecogniser from the view ?

Comment: Yes indeedy!  All you need to do is to call the view's `removeGestureRecognizer:` method.  [Details here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW101)